# Laravel rendering view with proper URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So my view `users` contains a list of all registered users. It also features a button to delete a specific user, so I created a controller and a route

```
users/delete/this@somemailaddress.com
```

in my controller, `UsersController`, I handle the delete action. The user gets deleted and I return to `users` with an `success alert` which states that the user was deleted.

```
$message = "User ".$user. " successfully deleted";
return View::make('users')->with(compact('message'));
```

which works, the alert is displayed. However, Chrome displays `localhost:8000/users/delete/this@somemailaddress.com`, which I can understand since I just 'make' (render) the `users` view within the `users/delete/{email}` route. Now that I'm really new to Laravel (and SO, so please be understanding) I wonder how to get Chrome to display `localhost:8000/users` and still show the message. I'm merely confused.

Comment: Obvioulsy you need to redirect to proper url after deleting a user.

Comment: Well, yes, but I still want to display the `success alert` and its message is passed to the view by $message. And thus, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called "flash messages". Here is an example:

On your controller you redirect with the message.

```
return redirect('users')->with('status', 'User deleted!');
```

After you simply have to display the message on the view like this.

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Here is more documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: All right, this looks interesting. What if I wanted to pass an array through? Does it work without further ado?

Comment: Yes you can also use an array, that should work fine.